# Create groups around a mark in R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, panel-data

New R user here.
I'm working with a panel dataset and I need to create groups around a marker.
The dataset looks like this

```
structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Bangladesh", 
"Barbados", "Benin", "Burundi", "Cameroon", "Chile", "Cyprus", 
"Ecuador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Gabon", "Ghana", "Guatemala", 
"Guinea", "Guyana", "Haiti", "India", "Jordan", "Lebanon", "Liberia", 
"Madagascar", "Mali", "Mexico", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Nepal", 
"Nicaragua", "Niger", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", 
"Peru", "Rwanda", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", 
"Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Togo", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Uganda", 
"Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = c("pseries", "factor")), date = structure(12:31, .Label = c("1965", 
"1966", "1967", "1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "1972", "1973", 
"1974", "1975", "1976", "1977", "1978", "1979", "1980", "1981", 
"1982", "1983", "1984", "1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", "1989", 
"1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", 
"1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", 
"2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", 
"2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018"), class = c("pseries", 
"factor")), oda_gdp_cyclical = c(-0.0324935877598818, -0.00752600677202254, 
0.0189276427016587, 0.0157818139406085, 0.0124581749631083, -0.00540096623366293, 
0.0277213961736074, -0.0212109456439322, 0.0042184336739809, 
-0.00749022185426284, -0.00583126153715459, 0.0109793841538662, 
-0.00802428451793625, 0.00528596069421613, 0.0179370088331591, 
7.18645244752135e-05, 0.000703793610724401, -0.0111594103693246, 
0.00294080442969348, -0.0142329769770062), episode = c(0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), epi_id = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), output = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
20L))
```

The idea is to group rows around the variable episode. This should include 2 rows before the first occurence of episode==1 and up to (though maybe less because of overlaps) 5 rows after the first occurence of episode==1. The different episodes are marked by the variable "epi_id"
The desired variable is called output.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure output == 3 starts at row 13, it seems it should start at row 15.

Comment: Yes! The idea is to select two rows before the first time episode==1 for each epi_id